# simple vector multiplication

Tags: calculus

can anyone explain why n1 x n2 is (-1,7,26)

I thought it is n1= (5,-3,1)

and

n2=(2,4,-1)

(5,3,1) * (2,4,-1)   =   (10,12,-1)

what am i missing here?

here is the example I can't figure out

[image]

Comment: you're confusing scalar product and vector product. See Wikipedia on this.

Comment: Should be $(5,-3,1)$, first of all. Second of all, you need the **cross product** of the vectors, not the dot product (which you have calculated incorrectly).

Answer (score 1):

You need the **cross product** (also called *vector product*) of $\textbf{n}_1$ and $\textbf{n}_2$, written as $\textbf{n}_1 \times \textbf{n}_2$. This can be computed as a determinant of a matrix in the following way (where $n_{\ell}^{(x)}$, $n_{\ell}^{(y)}$, and $n_{\ell}^{(z)}$ are the first, second, and third components of $\textbf{n}_{\ell}$ for $\ell = 1,2$, and $\vec{i}$, $\vec{j}$, $\vec{k}$ are the three unit vectors in the $x$, $y$, and $z$ directions, respectively):

$$ \begin{align} \textbf{n}_1 \times \textbf{n}_2 &= \text{det}\begin{pmatrix} \vec{i} & \vec{j} & \vec{k} \\ n_{1}^{(x)} & n_{1}^{(y)} & n_{1}^{(z)} \\ n_{2}^{(x)} & n_{2}^{(y)} & n_{2}^{(z)} \end{pmatrix} \\&= \text{det} \begin{pmatrix} \vec{i} & \vec{j} & \vec{k} \\ 5 & -3 & 1 \\ 2 & 4 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \\&= \text{det}\begin{pmatrix} -3 & 1 \\ 4 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\vec{i} - \text{det}\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 1 \\ 2 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\vec{j} + \text{det}\begin{pmatrix} 5 & -3 \\ 2 & 4 \end{pmatrix}\vec{k} \\&= -\vec{i} + 7\vec{j} + 26\vec{k} \\&= (-1,7,26) \,\,. \end{align}$$

Thus, taking $x = 0$ (allowable since this is the entire $yz$-plane), we obtain a reduced system. And, solving this, we get the point $(0,7,31)$.  It follows that any line perpendicular to the plane described has the form
$$(0,7,31) + t(-1,7,26) \,\,\,\text{for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$}\,.$$

On the other hand, the **dot product** (also called *scalar product*) of the two vectors is computed as follows, for future reference:

$$\begin{align} \textbf{n}_1 \cdot \textbf{n}_2 &= (n_{1}^{(x)},n_{1}^{(y)},n_{1}^{(z)}) \cdot (n_{2}^{(x)},n_{2}^{(y)},n_{2}^{(z)}) \\&= n_{1}^{(x)}n_{2}^{(x)} + n_{1}^{(y)}n_{2}^{(y)} + n_{1}^{(z)}n_{2}^{(z)} \\&= 5(2) -3(4) + 1(-1) \\&= -3 \,\,. \end{align}$$